# Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.content.Context' to 'com.example.xxxxx.PendingListFragment'

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I'm try to set button on list view using `CursorLoader`. But it gives me error message saying

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.content.Context' to 'com.example.xxxxx.PendingListFragment'.

I'm new to android, please answer.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    final Button signUpButton = view.findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);

    TextView nameTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    final int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(InfoContract.InfoEntry._ID);
    int nameColumnIndex = 
    cursor.getColumnIndex(InfoContract.InfoEntry.COLUMN_NAME); 

    String name = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
    String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberColumnIndex);
    final String col = cursor.getString(id);

    nameTextView.setText(name);
    signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                PendingListFragment pendingListFragment =  (PendingListFragment)context;
                pendingListFragment.upDateStatus(Integer.valueOf(col), InfoContract.InfoEntry.STATUS_SIGN_UP);

        }
    });
}
```

Code for PendingListFragment is here

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.xxxxx.data.InfoContract;

public class PendingListFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int INFO_LOADER = 0;
    PendingListCursorAdapter pendingListCursorAdapter;
    Cursor cursor;
    private ListView mInfoListView;
    private View mEmptyView;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstantState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pending_list, container, false);
        mInfoListView = view.findViewById(R.id.pending_list_view);
        mEmptyView = view.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstantState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstantState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Pending List");
        pendingListCursorAdapter = new PendingListCursorAdapter(getActivity(), null);
        mInfoListView.setAdapter(pendingListCursorAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(INFO_LOADER, null, PendingListFragment.this);


        mInfoListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyView);

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] projection = {
                InfoContract.InfoEntry._ID,
                InfoContract.InfoEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
                InfoContract.InfoEntry.COLUMN_MOBILE_NUMBER,
                InfoContract.InfoEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
                InfoContract.InfoEntry.COLUMN_STATUS
        };
        return new CursorLoader(getContext(),
                InfoContract.InfoEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                null);
    }
    public void upDateStatus(Integer id, int status) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(InfoContract.InfoEntry.COLUMN_STATUS, status);
        Uri upDateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(InfoContract.InfoEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);
        int rowsAffected = getActivity().getContentResolver().update(upDateUri, values, null, null);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        pendingListCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        pendingListCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);

    }
}
`



when button is clicked it need to update database.
```

Comment: what is the reason that a context could be a `PendingListFragment`? Why at all would you expect some random `context` to be your fragment?

Answer (score 0):

`PendingListFragment pendingListFragment = new PendingListFragment();` initialise like this

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference

Comment: can you post the Fragment class?

Comment: I added Fragment class

Comment: try changing `getActivity()` in `int rowsAffected = getActivity().getContentResolver().update(upDateUri, values, null, null);` to `getContext()`

Comment: pass `context` in `pendingListFragment.upDateStatus(Integer.valueOf(col), InfoContract.InfoEntry.STATUS_SIGN_UP); ` and then recieve it in your method definition and use that context instead of `getActivity()`

Comment: still not working. I tried like this pendingListFragment. upDateStatus(Integer. valueOf(col), 1,context) ; and public void upDateStatus(Integer id, int status, Context context) { ContentValues values = new ContentValues() ;  values. put(InfoContract.InfoEntry.COLUMN_STATUS, status) ;  Uri upDateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(InfoContract.InfoEntry.CONTENT_URI, id) ;  int rowsAffected = context.getContextResolver().update(updateUri, values, null, null) ;  }

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because you are trying to **type cast** current context of the application to *PendingListFragment* which is wrong and since you simply need to call the method of your PendingListFragment all you need to do is create it's object which can be acheived in java by make use of **new** keyword.

So to do that simply write

```
PendingListFragment pendingListFragment = new PendingListFragment(); //this will create new object of your PendingListFragmnet which will allow you to access it's method.
pendingListFragment.upDateStatus(Integer.valueOf(col), InfoContract.InfoEntry.STATUS_SIGN_UP);
```

Also make sure that your upDateStatus method is public.